Using Redux-Toolkit slice action with class components via connect HOC, does it require dispatch or not?
I have been working on an older code base with class components using Redux connect HOC. There are few RTK slices introduced before. I am abit confused as to why these 2 ways of using the action from the slice is working correctly (can see in Redux Toolkit that ways update the state and appear in the Actions panel (left hand side).
2 ways:

with dispatch (updateAbc)
without dispatch (updateXyz)

See example below
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
    return {
        updateAbc: (params) => dispatch(updateAbc(params)),
        updateXyz,
    }
}

Both are from the slice file:
const sampleSlice = createSlice({
   name: 'sample',
   initialState: {},
   reducers: {
      updateAbc: () => { /* do something */},
      updateXyz: () => { /* do something */}
   }
})
const { actions, reducer } = sampleSlice
export const {
    updateAbc,
    updateXyz,
} = actions


How come both are working or am I missing something or they are just both valid ways (but I don't see how it dispatches it without the explicit call to dispatch)?


How come both are working or am I missing something or they are just
both valid ways (but I don't see how it dispatches it without the
explicit call to dispatch)?

They are both valid ways to decorate the actions in the connectDispatchToProps helper. See the Object Shorthand Form for details. Note that the emphasis is mine.

mapDispatchToProps may be an object where each field is an action
creator.
import { addTodo, deleteTodo, toggleTodo } from './actionCreators'

const mapDispatchToProps = {
  addTodo,
  deleteTodo,
  toggleTodo,
}

export default connect(null, mapDispatchToProps)(TodoApp)

In this case, React-Redux binds the dispatch of your store to
each of the action creators using bindActionCreators.

What this means for your code is that updateXyz gets wrapped in a call to dispatch "auto-magically".
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
  return {
    updateAbc: (params) => dispatch(updateAbc(params)),
    updateXyz, // <-- dispatch bound to action creator
  }
}

The more typical mapDispatchToProps would be written as follows:
const mapDispatchToProps = {
  updateAbc,
  updateXyz,
}


Thanks for siting the documentation link that explains this, I totally missed that while looking at the RTK docs, I can see this one is in the older connect HOC - thanks!

@CarlosJaimeC.DeLeon Yeah, for sure. Also, FWIW, using the connect HOC is now considered a bit outdated. In modern Redux we use the useDispatch and useSelector hooks to dispatch actions to and subscribe to changes from the store. Cheers and good luck!

yes agree, however the codebase I am working on is very old, it has mix of class components and functional components, when we have time we definitely would love to rewrite the class components but business will probably disagree as they want new features lol

@CarlosJaimeC.DeLeon Business wants features, a tale as old as time.
